# SCIP: get sensitivity range of the objective function coefficient of a variable

Tags: scip

I am implementing a branching rule in SCIP (using the C api). During the *BRANCHEXECLP* callback, I need to get the *sensitivity range of the objective function coefficient* of the candidates variables. Is there a way to get this information?

I want a function to get a range `[x1, x2]` for a variable `x` such that changing the objective coefficient of `x` by a value in this range does not change the optimal solution of the LP relaxation.

Comment: by not changing the optimal solution do you mean not changing the objective value or not changing the variable assignments (or both?)? I can already tell you that there is no already implemented functions that gives you this, but it might be possible with a bit of work, depending on what exactly you want.

Comment: Not changing the variable assignment. I might be able to do so by doing as in [this example](https://web.mit.edu/15.053/www/AMP-Chapter-03.pdf) (page 9), but it requires the final state of the simplex tableau, is it directly available? Or must I compute also it myself?

Comment: All the data from the final Basis should be directly available to you (real LP solvers do not actually compute a simplex tableau explicitly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I think you only need to query the reduced costs, as well as the tableau coefficients.
The reduced cost you get from calling `SCIPgetVarRedcost`. For the tableau row you should call `SCIPgetLPBInvARow`